# Print Array Separated By Comma's

Tags: java, arrays, printing, element

I need to print this array without having he last array item print with a comma. I have tried setting i to be less than 3 but it will not work. :/ I cannot get this last array entry to print all by itself. This is homework so please do not feel the need to give me the answer just a nudge in the right direction would help!

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class PrintWithComma {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
      final int NUM_VALS = 4;
      int[] hourlyTemp = new int[NUM_VALS];
      int i = 0;

      hourlyTemp[0] = 90;
      hourlyTemp[1] = 92;
      hourlyTemp[2] = 94;
      hourlyTemp[3] = 95;

      for(i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; i++){
         if(hourlyTemp[i] < NUM_VALS);
         System.out.print(hourlyTemp[i]);
      }

      System.out.println("");

      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: what output are you expecting ?

Comment: I don't see where you print the coma. Your if clause inside for has no effect (you have ; just after the closing bracket ), so system.out.print is always called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want a nudge in the correct direction,

```
if(hourlyTemp[i] < NUM_VALS);
```

Remove the semicolon at the end of that `if` (it terminates the `if` body). Also, I suggest you always use braces

```
if(hourlyTemp[i] < NUM_VALS) {
    // ...
}
```

I also think you wanted `i + 1 < NUM_VALS` and `System.out.print(", ");` Of course, you might also use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hourlyTemp));
```

**Edit**
Based on your comment below you seem to want something like

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.print(hourlyTemp[i]);
}
System.out.println("");
```

Comment: Yes that code turned out to be messed up. That was not my original code I must have accidentally messed it up. I edited my code with those tips and I seem to be getting the code to -                                                                                                                   for(i = 0; i + 1 < NUM_VALS; i++){
         if(i < NUM_VALS)
            System.out.print(hourlyTemp[i] + ", ");
         }                                                                           I am expecting to see {90, 92, 94, 95} but i get {90, 92, 94,}. Im now more lost lol

Comment: That worked exactly as expected. Would the if statement keep it from getting a comma on element 0? Iv been staring at code all day maybe im just starting to lose the ability to think logically hah.

Comment: Yes, the first element (0).